# How can I turn off the 555 IC using MCU GPIO?

Tags: circuit-analysis, pwm, 555, npn

This is a simple circuit: PWM motor controller circuit using switch potentiometer

[image]

I want to turn the 555 IC on/off. But it didn't work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Didn't work in reality or simulation? What does 'didn't work' mean? When MCU_GPIO is high the 555 still oscillates?

Comment: Try making R? more like 10 kohm.

Comment: @Andy aka oh R? (1K) i changed 10K and it works! thank you!

Comment: @Antonio51 C3 is only connected 'CV' and 'GND' is this wrong?

Comment: @spehroPefhany in reality, i wired on board. when MCU_GPIO on 555 OFF

Comment: @KimJiHoon Sorry. It is ok.

Comment: Not to do with your problem but move R27 to connect across the GPIO and GND. Otherwise, you're needlessly creating a potential divider. Just a good practice to get into.

Comment: @TonyM thank you great tip!

Answer (score 1):

This simple one seems to work.

[image]

Comment: Is the VC pin connected directly to the gpio on the MCU?

Comment: No. Just a label to show the capacitor voltage. Just "rst" wired to MCU.

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to turn the 555 IC on/off. But it didn't work. How can I fix
> it?*

Try making "R?" more like 10 kohm. – Andy aka

> *@Andy aka oh R? (1K) i changed 10K and it works! thank you! –
> KimJiHoon*